# react node server request port change

Tags: node.js, reactjs, rest, postman, fetch-api

I am trying to build a web app with React (v16.8.6) and Node (v.12.16.2).

Both in my local and cloud server, api call with fetch/get works okay for the first two times (maybe three sometimes). But, then after these two or three times, api call fails.

**UPDATE**

So, I tested cloud server with postman. "GET" request works first few times, and then `Error: socket hang up` comes up. It is not just /usr-info, but all the other "GET" requests in index.js that I send (e.g. /some-other-info, /another-info, etc). So, I searched what this error was and some say that it is related to port or vpn. I tested the same request in localhost. Although it takes some time, it eventually returns what it is supposed to in localhost (takes about a min or two). I even just typed `cloud_ip:4200/usr-info` in url, and it behaves the same. It works first few times, but after some refreshing, it gives `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`

Here is my code.

**package.json**

```
{
    ...
    "proxy": "https://localhost (or cloud public ip):4200",
    ...
    "scripts": {
        "start": "env-cmd -f .env.development react-app-rewired start",
        "run": "env-cmd -f .env.development node server/index.js",
        "start:prod": "env-cmd -f .env.production react-app-wired start",
        "run:prod": "env-cmd -f .env.production node server/index.js"
    }
}
```

**login.jsx**

```
const login = () => {
    const [dbUserInfo, setDbUserInfo] = useState([]);

    const getData = async (route) => {
        // for getting user info and other data after checking login info
        const response = await fetch(route);
        return response.json();
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        // setLoading() just for test purpose. It disables signin button.
        setLoading(true)
        getData('/usr-info').then((res) => { setDbUserInfo(res); setLoading(false); }).catch(error = > console.log(error));
    }, []);
    ...
}
```

**index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const mysql = require('mysql');

const conn = mysql.createPool({
    host: host,
    user: user,
    password: password,
    database: 'database'
})

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

app.get('/usr-info', function (req, res) {
    conn.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
        connection.query('SELECT * from TABLE where COL = "VAL1"', function (error,results, fields) {
            if (error) throw error;

            res.send(results)
        });
    });
});

app.listen(4200, () => {
    console.log('server started on 4200')
})
```

Basically, in login.jsx, I am getting user inputs (id & password) and comparing that to the ones in DB. I am fetching data when the page loads using useEffect. setLoading in useEffect is just for me to see if api call is done or not. I think this is where the problem lies.

After I logged in and out two or three times, signin button is disabled for a minute or two in local, and forever in cloud. When I tried to enter username and password right when the signin button is disabled, it gives undefined error because dbUserInfo is null and cannot find matching login info to input.

Right after I get null error, if I hit the refresh button, I get proxy error.

> Proxy error: Could not proxy request /usr-info from localhost(or cloud public ip):3000 to localhost(or cloud public ip):4200.

Why does this work for the first two or three times, but not after that? I saw a SO post about res.send(), but I have that in index.js. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61349015/create-react-app-express-proxy-error-could-not-proxy-request-econnreset) talks about event.preventDefault() in handleSubmit, and I tried that, but it did not work.

So, I am guessing the api call to server (4200) from client (3000) is not finished from the first two or three times, and it breaks? Or it may be some other issues, but I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

So, I found a fix from this SO question([Node/Express pending request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19397161/node-express-pending-request)).

It turns out the problem was connection pool staying full and the subsequent request stalled.

The reason why I got all these errors after two or three times is because there was no available connection in pool. No available connection, no response, thus errors that I have got. And it worked the first two or three times because right after the server was up and running, the pool was empty and as I sent request, the pool got filled and stayed full.

As the link says, I added connection.release() in connection.query() to free the sql connection like so.

**index.js**

```
...
app.get('/usr-info', function (req, res) {
    conn.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
        connection.query('SELECT * from TABLE where COL = "VAL1"', function (error,results, fields) {
            if (error) throw error;
            connection.release();  // added
            res.send(results)
        });
    });
});
...
```

After I added connection.release(), no matter how many requests I send, I always got response both in local and cloud **AND** both in web app and postman.